# Text before maketitle

Tags: header-footer, positioning, titles

[image]

My goal is to put text before `\maketitle` as well as on left side, and on the right. They should be on the same level. I've tried `\begingroup` -- doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, twoside, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[MeX]{polski}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
        \renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
        \renewcommand\numberline[1]{#1.\hskip0.7em}
        \renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\makeatother


\usepackage[%
   headheight=25pt,
   includeheadfoot,
   margin=2cm
   ]{geometry}
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   \hypersetup
   {    
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=gray,
    pdfmenubar=false,
    pdftex
   }

   \frenchspacing
   \title{Tytul}       
   \author{Iksinski}
   \date{some date}

   \begin{document}


   \begin{flushright}
   right text
   \end{flushright}
   \begin{flushleft}
   left one
   \end{flushleft}
   \begingroup
   \let\newpage\relax% Void the actions of \newpage
   \maketitle
   \endgroup

   \maketitle
   \end{document}
```

Comment: There is no information to the left/right of the contents of `\maketitle` in your example image. There is contents in the *header* of the page and stuff (abstract and keywords) *below* it though, but that's not what you're after in your problem description.

Comment: So it is in a header. Thank you. I thought that is some thing before title.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the image you provided, you need to create a custom header that includes some content. The easiest way to do this, depending on your requirements or limitations, would be to use the [`fancyhdr` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). For example, creating a "title" header you could use:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\fancypagestyle{title}{%
  \setlength{\headheight}{22pt}%
  \fancyhf{}% No header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}% Page number in Centre of footer
  \fancyhead[L]{\small\begin{tabular}{@{}l}Psycological Assessment​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​\\2011, Vol.\ 23​​​​​​​, No.\ 1, 64--79\end{tabular}}
  \fancyhead[R]{\small\begin{tabular}{@{}r}\copyright~2001​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ American Psycological Association\\1040-1234567890~XYZ:\ 8472302\end{tabular}}
}%
\title{Here is my title}
\author{Some Author}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{title}

​\lipsum
\end{document}​​​​​
```

If your document class provides an interface to the headers (for conference or paper/article submissions, say), it's best to use that.

Read the [`fancyhdr` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) for more information on the commands used and how to modify the respective header/footer locations/contents.

Comment: But if i add a \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} it dosne't work correct. How to make it work?

Comment: @DanielMiliński: What does "it doesn't work correct" mean? Do you receive an error? If so, what's the error? If not, is the layout different? Show a picture of the incorrect layout then...

Comment: @Werner I've got the same exact needs, so I've tried your solution but it is not working. What I get is exactly \maketitle coverpage. Can it depend on the fact that my documentclass is report? how can i solve it?

Comment: @Mengops: Yes, `report` sets the title as a single page by default when you issue `\maketitle`. Anything placed in front of `\maketitle` will be on its own page, as well as the actual title.

Answer (score 8):

Don't specify the `twocolumn` document class option. Instead, load the `multicol` package and execute the command `\begin{multicols}{2}` after `\maketitle` -- as well as `\end{multicols}` before `\end{document}`, of course. That way, you can typeset various things *before* the title stuff gets typeset with the `\maketitle` command.

The following, simplified, version of your MWE illustrates how this may be done.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[MeX]{polski}

\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
\title{Tytul}       
\author{Iksinski}
\date{some date}

\begin{document}
\noindent
left-hand text \hspace{\fill} right-hand text\\
more left-hand text \hspace{\fill} more right-hand text

\begingroup
\let\newpage\relax
\maketitle
\endgroup

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1] % filler text
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i think the left-hand text and right-hand text are supposed to have the same baseline.

Comment: @barbarabeeton -- thanks for pointing this out; I'll modify the MWE accordingly.

Comment: but the visual shown does have the two parts aligned at their tops; this is a common format for logos for a translation journal.  this format is used by ams in the "st. petersburg math journal", for which an author package exists (linked from the [ams journal author packages](http://www.ams.org/journals/journalpackages) page); the coding is very specific to tha `amsart` package, so may or may not be of help.

Comment: @barbarabeeton -- Thanks. I've updated the MWE to reflect this requirement.